# Gerar gráfico mensal

Tags: php, mysql

Estou montando um gráfico mensal onde é exibida a soma de despesas e receitas por dia, porém os dados exibidos no gráfico são somente as datas que existem no banco `mysql`. 
Como eu poderia exibir as datas que não existam no banco?
Queria exibir por ex do dia 01 até o dia 31 do mês.

Já tentei fazer um `for` e alimentar um `array` mas sem sucesso, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Com certeza que isto poderia ser resolvido na tua applicação. Mas fica aqui uma alternativa para solucionar isto na base de dados.

Esta é uma solução para um problema bastante conhecido.

```
select b.Data, a.id, a.valor 
from tbl_tabela a
right join 
(
    select curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) + (1000 * d.a)) DAY as data
    from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as d
) b
  on b.data = a.data
where b.Data between '2015-05-01' and '2015-05-03'
```

Apenas substitui tbl_tabela, pela tua tabela e ajusta as condições de acordo com as tuas necessidades.

Caso a performance seja um problema (nos testes que fiz, não é de todo um problema), podes pensar em criar uma tabela Calendario com as datas que necessitas.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45d3b/3)